# R: creating a vector of 1/n weights using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

For the sake of making this general enough to be useful for others, I have six friends:

```
friends <- c("luke", "leia", "han", "chewy", "lando", "obi")
```

That I am trying to give them each a portion of cake using a for loop

```
portions <- for (portion in length(friends)){
                 portion = 1/portion
}
```

My code returns the correct portion size (~16%), but does not populate my `portions` vector with what I was hoping for:
`(0.16,0.16,0.16,0.16,0.16,0.16)`

Cutsie examples aside, I am looking to for a solution which can be applied to creating weights for several hundred variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need `rep(1/length(friends), length(friends))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just do `rep` on the `1/length(friends)` and it would give the expected output without any other calculations

```
rep(1/length(friends), length(friends))
#[1] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

---

In the `for` loop, we are only assigning to `portion` each time and it gets updated.  Instead, an optioin  is to pre-assign a vector and assign it to it

```
portion <- numeric(length(friends))
for(i in seq_along(friends)) portion[i] <- 1/length(friends)
portion
#[1] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
prop.table(table(friends))

#friends
#chewy   han lando  leia  luke   obi 
#0.167 0.167 0.167 0.167 0.167 0.167
```

Or

```
table(friends)/length(friends)
```